# What is the difference in the wording of these questions?

Tags: actuarial-science, compound-interest

Question 1: An account with an initial amount B earns compound interest at an annual effective interest rate $i$. The interest in the third year is $426$ and the discount in the seventh year is $812$. Find $i$.

The work for question 1 is simple:

$$\dfrac{B(1+i)^7}{B(1+i)^3} = \dfrac{812}{426}$$

This leads you to $i = 17.5 \%$

Question 2: The amount of interest on X for two years is $320$. The amount of discount on X for one year is $148$. Find the annual effective interest rate $i$ and the value of X.

The work for question 2 is much more complex: it involves setting up $X(1+i)^2 - X = 320$ and $X - \dfrac{X}{1+i} = 148$, then solving for X and i, leading to $i = .053$ and $X = 2934.48$.

What is the difference in wording between these two questions? How would I know which to do on an exam?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a difference in the questions as well. But I start in a different way at the first question:

> The interest in the third year is 426

This gives me the equation $B(1+i)^3-B(1+i)^2=426$

> ... and the discount in the seventh year is 812

Mathematically the term is $B(1+i)^7-B(1+i)^6=812$

Factoring out

\begin{align}
&  B(1+i)^2\cdot ((1+i)-1)=426 \\ &  B(1+i)^6\cdot (1+i)-1)=812\\ &  \\ &B(1+i)^2\cdot i=426 \\&  B(1+i)^6\cdot i=812\\ & \\ & \textrm{Dividing one equation by the other } \\ & (1+i)^4=\frac{812}{426}
\end{align}

So basically the set up for the first question is not different to the set up for the second question-beside the term "discount".